# How to make a REST get request to Geoserver in Python?

Tags: python, geoserver, rest

I was wondering how to make a GET request to geoserver 2.6 in Python.

```
import urllib2, json
url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces.json'  
authKey = 'admin:geoserver'
headers ={'Authorization': "Basic " + authKey}
params = {}
request = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(params), headers)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=30).read()
    print json.loads(response)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e
    print e.header
    print e.read()
```

with code above, I get HTTP Error 500: Server Error.
If I set the value of authKey to '', then I get "HTTP Error 401: Full authentication is required to access this resource"

So how can I set up the request header with authorization?

---

Update:
    I print e.headers in the exception, then I got:

```
Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2015 15:33:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 6639
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(7.6.13.v20130916)
```

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im?

Comment: not really. I have updated the header information when exception happens.

Comment: What does e.read() return?  Perhaps the contents of the HTTPError provide some details.

Comment: e.read() returns:  "Could not determine format. Try setting the Content-type header.".   Then I specify the the 'Content-type':'application.json' in the headers variable, the 'print e' returns "HTTP Error 500: Server error". And 'print e.read()' returns nothing. Geoserver document says error 500 often donates a syntax error in the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a REST example that works on GWC, so I'll set it up so it's shared: https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/c39c3f520102c30e4dec

Here's the meaty bits:

```
url = baseURL + layer + '.json'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (un, pw)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
data = {'seedRequest':{'minX':[],'minY':[],'maxX':[],'maxY':[],'gridSetId':'EPSG:900913','zoomStart':00,'zoomStop':18,'format':'image/png','type':'seed','threadCount':2}}
data = json.dumps(data)
request.add_data(data)
req = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, alexgleith!

The problem in my simple code is:

`authKey = 'admin:geoserver'
  request = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(params), headers)`

should be replaced as:

```
authKey = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (un, pw)).replace('\n', '')
request = urllib2.Request(url)
for k in headers.keys():
    request.add_header(k, headers[k])
```